# How can I dynamically put an input element inside my form and not redundantly be added using a button to trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I put inside a status, It is working and I appended an element inside my div. The problem is this, if I set my data to inactive it will release an input element and then when I click active it is okay none will appear, however if I click again the button, an element will be added. How should I trap this?

Here is the image of my form

[image]

Here is my javascript code

```
    $(document).on('click', '.status_checks', function() {

    var status = '1';
    var selector = $(this);
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    if ($(this).hasClass("btn-success")) {
        status = '0';

        $("#reason").append(
            '<div><label> Reason for making it inactive? </label><font color=red>*</font></div>');

        var input = $('<input>', {
            id: 'reason_elem',
            name: 'reason_input_elem',
            type: 'text',
            class: 'form-control has-error has-danger',
            focusin: function() {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        }).appendTo('#reason');
    }
    // alert(status);
    selector.hasClass("btn-success") ? (selector.removeClass("btn-success").addClass(
        "btn-danger"),
    selector.text("Inactive")) : (selector.removeClass("btn-danger").addClass(
        "btn-success"),
    selector.text("Active"));
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label"> Status <font color="red">*
           </font></label>
           <div class="form-group">
           <p name="stats" data-id="<?php echo $rows['ID'];?>"
            class="status_checks statusButton <?php echo ($rows['status'])? 
            'btn-success': 'btn-danger'?>">
              <?php echo ($rows['status'])? 
              'Active' : 'Inactive'?>
          </p>
        </div>
   </div>

<div id="reason">
</div>
```

Comment: You can simply empty that div before appending new datas i.e : `$("#reason").html("")`

Comment: Hi @Swati yes I did that awhile ago but then when I click active the element is not being remove.

Comment: Put that line outside `if-statement` so that it will execute everytime whenever any `p` tag is clicked.